# Metasploit module for NULL LDAP credentials

Tags: exploit, metasploit, ctf, ldap

This [article](https://pentesterlab.com/exercises/web_for_pentester/course) covers the solution for the LDAP challenges on a capture the flag.

I understand how the first example works, using the NULL value for the username and password to authenticate to the LDAP exploiting NULL Bind. I understood the tutorial and how to do it manually, and I successfully completed the challenge.

I was curious if there was an msfconsole module for performing this attack, without having to do this manually?

Comment: https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/blob/master/documentation/modules/auxiliary/gather/ldap_hashdump.md seems to do a dump via anonymous bind

Comment: @RodrigoMurillo I assume you mean this part of the tutorial (Avaya Communication Manager via anonymous bind), however it seems the PASS_ATTR has been set, so how is this NULL LDAP credentials? Sorry if this is a stupid question.